# How to know which menu option has a user clicked in Microsoft Word (using Python)?

Tags: python, ms-office, win32gui

I actually just want to know if the user has been clicked on "Home" button and selected "Print" (as shown in the picture below) OR the user is in Print section. Unfortunately the Print section of Microsoft Office products is not a separate dialog box, so I can't catch the dialog window title and know that the user is about to print something. So I have to use other strategies.

MS Word print section

[image: MS-Word print section]

Comment: can you share the Minimal, Reproducible code and error that you are getting to better understand the issue? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: There are no errors. The problem is that I couldn't find any documentary for the purpose of "how to be able to monitore the (click) activites of a user on Microsoft Products". I've searched through some books like "Python Programming on Win32" and red posts about win32gui and win32api and Microsoft Documentary & so on without success.  I've used until now the pyautogui.locateOnScreen, with which I could be able to know that user is on Print Section. But my Boss asked me to do it in another way, which I can understand why.